# How can I know a where-clause query results contains another where-clause query results?

Tags: java, sql

How can I know a where-clause's query-results contains another where-clause's query-results?
For example:

```
"id>0" contains "id>1"
"id>0 or name='China'" contains "id>1"
"id>0 or name='China'" contains "name='China'"
```

Sorry,My English proficiency is very bad.

There is a table: Countries(id,name).

```
id      name
0       America
1       China
2       Japan
3       England
```

Obviously,The query-results of `select id, name from Countries where id>0` contains `select id, name from Countries id>2`'s.
I want to get the result by comparing  the two where-clauses directly,  I don't want to execute the actual query operation

I use java.

Comment: is there anyone who understood this question ?? i want to flag this but i am not sure

Comment: I;m not sure I understand the question. Are you asking if it is possible to execute a query that uses a `WHERE` clause and then run a  new query with a new `WHERE` clause on top of that? If so, that's perfectly possible using a sub query. i.e. `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id = 1) AS Table1 WHERE country = 'US'`

Comment: My English proficiency is very bad。

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data, so you have to run each where clauses by joining their results. You can join them and check if any result exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use set operators to compare the two. If query2 does not have any rows that aren't in query1, than query1 contains query2.

E.g., for Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  condtion2
MINUS
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  condtion1
```

For MS SQL Server and PostgreSQL, use `EXCEPT` instead of `MINUS`.

Comment: Exactly that, except that OP wants to find out _without_ running the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you'd need a way to represent your condition *other* than just text. Without fleshing out all of the classes, below should get the gist of it.

```
public abstract class Condition implements Comparable<C extends Condition> {
    public abstract boolean equals(C other);
    public abstract boolean contains(C other);
};

public class OrCondition extends Condition {
    // contains a list of the conditions it's OR-ring together

    public boolean contains(Condition other) {
        // true if the list of conditions 
        // contains a condition c such that c.equals(other)
    }
}

public class GreaterThanCondition extends Condition {
    // contains a fieldname and a number to compare it to

    public boolean contains(Condition other) {
        // true if other is a GreaterThanCondition as well
        // on the same field and the number other.number >= this.number
    }
}
```

And so on. Comparing strings and coming up with other conditions is left as an exercise to the OP (or the reader, if the reader is inclined to do so).

---

Of course, this works up to a point. As soon as you want to answer questions that depend on the data, you have no choice but to execute *some* query. For instance, there is easier way to find out that `WHERE id > 1` contains `WHERE name > 'China'` than issueing the queries.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there any existed java library to implement the Condition interface?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.